# How to implement didSelectViewController

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I want to catch the event when someone switches between tabs.  I have the following two function in my appdelegate file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController * uitbc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbarcontroller"];
    uitbc.delegate = self;
    [self.window addSubview:uitbc.view];

    return YES;
}


- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"switching");
}
```

But the `NSLog(@"switching");` never fires.  The xcode issues a warning for the line `uitbc.delegate = self;` saying "Passing appdelegate const__strong to parameter of incompatible type id".

What am I doing wrong?  I'm just following the accepted answer found here, except i'm instantiating my tabbarcontroller form story board:

[how to get the event that switch tab menu on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041982/how-to-get-the-event-that-switch-tab-menu-on-iphone)

**Update**
Based on skram's suggestion, I wrote this for my appdelegate but the NSLOG(Switching) still doesn't fire:

```
@interface johnAppDelegate : UIResponder <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

I also updated my didFinishLauchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
tabBarController = self.window.rootViewController.tabBarController;
tabBarController.delegate = self;
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

Good thing is that nothing crashes.  I also no longer et the warning about incompatible types.   But still, didSelectViewController doesn't fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in my appdelegate.h file, I changed the line

```
@interface wscAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

to

```
@interface wscAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Then in my CustomTabBarController in the viewDidLoad function i added these lines:

```
wscAppDelegate *appDelegate = (wscAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.delegate = appDelegate;
```

Then in appdelegate.m file, I added this function

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{

NSLog(@"hooray this works");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled with this a lot but my UITabBarNavigationController is pretty far from AppDelegate to set it there, and the only way to actually make it work was to do it **not** in the viewDidLoad of the UITabBarController subclass itself, but in its:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [ super viewDidLayoutSubviews ];
    self.delegate = self;
}
```

And that solved it. Alternatively you can do it in any of the tab bar controlled viewcontrollers, but that just feels wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need your AppDelegate to conform to **`UITabBarControllerDelegate`** protocol. See below..

```
@interface YourAppDelegate : UIResponder <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Comment: Still not firing.  I updated my question to reflect this. Any other ideas?  Thanks

Comment: do you still get the warning?

Comment: The warning is gone so that's good.  Maybe i still haven't established some relationships here and there between my app delegate and the correct tabbarcontroller?