# Recognizing TabBar Touch Down

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'd like to put a short UI sound on when the user touches a tabbar item but - following proper UI practices - the sound should occur on touch down, not on touch release.

I could override **didSelectItem** in the tabbar view controller but that only plays the sound on touch release. Is there any method of intercepting the 'touch down' action? The TabBarItem class doesn't provide anything like **touchesBegan** (like the Table Cell View).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use touch events to intercept touch down of a tabbar but u can achieve same result using the below method to play sound when a tabbar item is pressed.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick (but only after I followed this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10906908/356105).